# TK and TTK looks very different, is possibly to make TTK looks like TK?

Tags: python, linux, tkinter, tk-toolkit, ttk

I am using python `tk` but because `tk` don't have a tab widget I use `ttk`'s Notebook widget and all right in Windows but when I switch to Linux with dark theme styles, it looks horrible.

[image]

I can't find a way to make it look like the original `tk` theme or the default `GTK` theme, is possibly to do this or some tab control with `tk`?

Comment: can't you use `tk` widgets instead of `ttk` widgets ?

Comment: @furas there is no a tab widget for common `tk` widgets =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I found a solution and is use of `pmw` toolkit, is like an extension for `tk` that provides tab controls with the main `tk` style.

[image: A Tab with tk styled gtk in linux]

Answer (score 1):

There is module `ttkthemes` with additional themes - but I don't know if you find theme for you.

```
pip install ttkthemes
```

Here simple code which displays names for all themes and you can click button to see theme.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import ttkthemes

root = tk.Tk()

root.style = ttkthemes.ThemedStyle()
    
for i, name in enumerate(sorted(root.style.theme_names())):
    b = ttk.Button(root, text=name, command=lambda name=name:root.style.theme_use(name))
    b.pack(fill='x')

root.mainloop()
```

Example theme `"Ubuntu"` and list of all themes.

[image]

Comment: I saw the themes, but it makes me change all to `ttk` widgets and loose the native style in other platforms, that is why I'm asking if is possibly make it looks like `GTK`